# Predicting Future CRC Value

Tags: hash, cryptography, crc, crc32

The following code shows CRC32 used in a forward-hash (where we hash the same item multiple times with persistent context):

```
In [1]: from zlib import crc32

In [2]: crc32('aaaa')
Out[2]: -1382488763

In [3]: crc32('aaaa',-1382488763)
Out[3]: -1081835450

In [4]: crc32('aaaa' * 2)
Out[4]: -1081835450
```

My question is this:
Given the known initial crc of `-1382488763`, can we predict the value of the forward hash without knowing the original content? To clarify... can I derive -1081835450 from -1382488763 alone?

Comment: There are ways to optimized crc calculations for a repeated item, but your question is asking if this can be done without knowing what the repeated item is.

Comment: OK, reread your question. So basically you are asking: knowing that I've input 4 elements, and knowing the result, can I reconstruct the input value `aaaa` with any kind of certainty? Note that `crc(32('aaaa', -1382488763)` doesn't make *any* kind of sense to me. CRC32 has *one* input parameter. If you have two then please specify what you mean with it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes according to [zlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) it is used as a starting value to produce running checksums.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes `crc32('aaaa',-1382488763)` means use the second argument as the initial CRC, and run the message `aaaa` through it. So it should give the same thing as taking the CRC of `aaaaaaaa`, which `Out[4]` indeed demonstrates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `crc32()` takes an initial CRC, applies the message to it, and gets the resulting CRC. You need the message.

If you could determine `crc32('aaaa',-1382488763)` without knowing the `aaaa`, then why would the `crc32()` function need the first argument at all?

If you want to know if you can compute the CRC of a repetition of a message given only the CRC of the unrepeated message, then no. However if you know the CRC of the message *and* the length of the message, then yes you can compute the CRC of two or more repetitions of the that message, without knowing the message itself. As you note in the comments, that is what `crc32_combine()` in zlib does.

Comment: Perhaps I could have specified more thoroughly... While I do not know the content of the checksummed buffer, I do know its length. Let's assume I had control of it previously, took its crc, and then deleted it. I managed to solve this by using your helpful crc32_combine function. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still not understanding. If all you know is -1382488763 is followed by four bytes, but you don't know the bytes, then you cannot predict the result -1081835450. You need to know those bytes, or at least you need to know their CRC (using the same polynomial).

Comment: Yes -- I know the bytes since they are always the same (I'm checksumming the same item over and over again, looping back the output into the following input.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, in a sense. There is only one 4 byte value: "AAAA" which produces the specific checksum. So it is possible to find this value *if* you know the output - e.g. by just iterating through all possible byte inputs. Then you can guess the next output by extending the CRC32 calculation by supplying the the previous message again.

Notes:

- I'm assuming ASCII encoding here;
- CRC32 is not a *one-way* hash so you could possibly calculate information about the input message without reverting to brute force;
- It's unclear to me why you would want to repeat the initial input message, I hope *you* know :)

Comment: The question was not knowing either the message _or_ the resulting CRC, can you determine the resulting CRC. Obviously not. Yes, if you know the message you can get the CRC, and if you know the CRC, you can get the 32-bit message. (By the way, the message can be solved for very very fast with straightforward linear algebra. So yes, you don't need to brute-force it.)

Comment: It seems clear to me that the org. message was to be repeated. Of course you cannot calculate *any* hash if you don't even what you're going to calculate it over. But in this case you 1. can calculate the original for the intermediate checksum 2. provide that to the intermediate CRC32 to calculate the final sum. So I have answered the question: if I *just* have an intermediate hash over 4 characters, say AAAA, can I possibly calculate the hash over AAAAAAAA. And yes, this is possible.

Comment: I'm just going by what the question actually says, which is "To clarify... can I derive -1081835450 from -1382488763 alone?" Apparently the "to clarify" did not in fact clarify the question.

Comment: I agree, the question remains unclear. This is the best we can do - except to vote to close, which I already did.